# create and update plugin in crm 2013 c#

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I need to write plugin in CRM 2013 that do two thing:

1. If statecode = 3 and the field el_meeting_in_outlook_id is empty I
   need to create a new appoitment.
2. If statecode = 3 and the field el_meeting_in_outlook_id is not empty
       I need to update an existing appoitment.

This is what I wrote:

```
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using tmura_Entity_Plugins;

namespace tmura_Entity__Plugins
{
    public class postCreateUpdateServiceAppointment : Plugin
    {
        public postCreateUpdateServiceAppointment()
            : base(typeof(postCreateUpdateServiceAppointment))
        {
            base.RegisteredEvents.Add(new Tuple<int, string, string, Action<LocalPluginContext>>(40, "Create", null, new Action<LocalPluginContext>(ExecutePostCreate)));
            base.RegisteredEvents.Add(new Tuple<int, string, string, Action<LocalPluginContext>>(40, "Update", null, new Action<LocalPluginContext>(ExecutePostUpdate)));

        }

        private void ExecutePostCreate(LocalPluginContext obj)
        {
            Logger.WriteMessage("Enter ExecutePostCreate", CrmLogService.MessageLevel.Info, "");
            if ((obj.PluginExecutionContext.InputParameters.Contains("Target")) && (obj.PluginExecutionContext.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity))
            {
                Entity serviceAppontment = (Entity)obj.PluginExecutionContext.InputParameters["Target"];
                if (serviceAppontment.LogicalName != "serviceappointment")
                    return;

                Logger.WriteMessage("", CrmLogService.MessageLevel.Info, "");

                if ((serviceAppontment.Attributes.Contains("statecode")) || ((int)(serviceAppontment.Attributes["statecode"]) == 3) && (serviceAppontment.Attributes["el_meeting_in_outlook_id"] == null))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Entity appointment = new Entity("appointment");
                        appointment.Attributes.Add("subject", "Opened automatically");
                        appointment.Attributes.Add("description", "Just Checking");
                        appointment.Attributes.Add("el_serviceappointment_id", new EntityReference("serviceappointment", serviceAppontment.Id));
                        appointment.Attributes.Add("scheduledstart", DateTime.Now.AddDays(7));
                        appointment.Attributes.Add("scheduledend", DateTime.Now.AddDays(7));

                        obj.OrganizationService.Create(appointment);
                    }                      
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Logger.WriteException(ex);
                    }
                }
                else if (((int)(serviceAppontment.Attributes["statecode"]) == 3) && (serviceAppontment.Attributes["el_meeting_in_outlook_id"] != null))
                {
                    //TODO
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know what to write in the second section that is supposed to update the appointment. I tried to search the web but with no success.

Can you please help?

Comment: Can I ask you why you have registered plugin on POST operation? It will cause UPDATE twice on same entity record. First time on actual process and second time UPDATE triggered through your plugin. It you register your plugin on PRE Operation that will be more suitable in given scenario. On the other hand, PRE Plugin will only update once.

Comment: well, this is the requirement task.I will check with my manager. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Where you have defined the registered events, you have to put "serviceappointment", that is the entity logical name, instead of null.

Then replace: `(serviceAppontment.Attributes.Contains("statecode")) || ((int)(serviceAppontment.Attributes["statecode"]) == 3)` by `(serviceAppontment.Attributes.Contains("statecode")) && ((OptionSetValue)(serviceAppontment.Attributes["statecode"]).Value == 3)`, because the field "statecode" is an OptionSet. Also replace the || by &&, because when `serviceAppontment.Attributes.Contains("statecode"))` is false, `((OptionSetValue)(serviceAppontment.Attributes["statecode"]).Value` will throw an NullReferenceException.

To update an existing appointment, looks like there is an lookup in appointment entity to serviceappointment entity. So, you have to retrieve all the appointments related with the serviceappointment. You can use this query:

```
QueryExpression queryExp = new QueryExpression
{
    EntityName = "appointment",
    ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("subject", "description", "scheduledstart", "scheduledend"),
    Criteria = new FilterExpression
    {
       Conditions = { new ConditionExpression("el_serviceappointment_id", ConditionOperator.Equal, serviceAppontment.Id) }
    }

};

EntityCollection collection = obj.OrganizationService.RetrieveMultiple(queryExp);

if (collection.Entities.Count > 0)
{
    // now that you have all the appointments related with the serviceappoitement 
    // you can update de any appointment you want
    obj.OrganizationService.Update(appointment);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. now i need to update my record. i need to insert a value to lookup field requiredattendees from the field from another lookup field in serviceappoitnment. Can you help me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

To update your record with a value in a lookup field in serviceappoitnment to may retrieve the serviceappoitment record `Entity svcApp = obj.OrganizationService.Retrieve(serviceAppontment.LogicalName, serviceAppontment.Id, new ColumnSet("<lookup_field_in_serviceappoitnment>");`

You need to add to the collumnset in the query expression the attribute requiredattendees, and then update the appoitment

```
if(appointment.Attributes.Contains("requiredattendees") == true)
{
    appointment.Attributes["requiredattendees"] = svcApp.Attributes["<lookup_field_in_serviceappoitnment>"];
}
else
{
    appointment.Attributes.Add("requiredattendees", svcApp.Attributes["<lookup_field_in_serviceappoitnment>");
}
```